# Link Table View to Unlock Appropriate ViewController after In App Purchase

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

Using RW's tutorial, i have managed to implement IAP as far as when the user Buys/Purchases the selected IAP and it shows a tick. it also successfully lists all 4 of my IAP available

I have decided to go about this in a way which is simpler and requires less code (i think)
- instead of adding more code to allow the user to download the apple hosted content and then code somemore to transfer the content back into the app and into a selected view

**i have instead chosen to imbed the content within the app and instead just lock the view controller or button linked to the appropriate view controller until the user has purchased the content/IAP.** i dont wanna change up RW's ways because it works just fine so far i just wanna add to it so that after the user purchases the content and it ticks the IAP, it then unlocks the view controller related to that specific IAP.

How do i go on about adding to the code so far so that i can achieve this? i have 4 in app purchases (meaning 4 separate view controllers to link to this code) i think the code i need to expand on is this below....

```
- (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSString * productIdentifier = notification.object;
    [_products enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SKProduct * product, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:productIdentifier]) {
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];

}

- (void)reload {
    _products = nil;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [[SecretsIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
        if (success) {
            _products = products;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _products.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) _products[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = product.localizedTitle;
    [_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];

    if ([[SecretsIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
    } else {
        UIButton *buyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        buyButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 72, 37);
        [buyButton setTitle:@"Buy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        buyButton.tag = indexPath.row;
        [buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.accessoryView = buyButton;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)buyButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    UIButton *buyButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    SKProduct *product = _products[buyButton.tag];

    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);
    [[SecretsIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];

}
```

Comment: Looks good. What is not working? The products array should contain the unlocked products, and the table should only show `_products.count` rows.

Comment: @mundi RW's code only goes as far as displaying the Tick after purchase which is the reason as to why i came up with this simpler solution so after the purchase... what can i add to this code so that the user is able to click on their in APP purchase and view Unlocked content? thanks for the reply by the way.

Comment: Just put the logic into `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: @Mundi - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
i take it you mean this line of code... how do you mean exactly? at the moment when i click on the IAP it takes me to the detail view screen.... however i would like to change it up so that for each of the 4 in app purchases it takes the user to a different unlocked view after they have purchased the content.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should solve typing this:

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
    DetailViewController * detailViewController = (DetailViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
    SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) _products[self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
    if ([[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier]) {

        if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"it.horizonmedia.testiap.ghesemmo"]) {

            detailViewController.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"drummer.png"];
            detailViewController.message = @"Bravo che l'hai COMPRATA!!!";
        }


          else if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"it.horizonmedia.testiap.prodottotest3"]) {
              detailViewController.message = @"Bravo che l'hai COMPRATA!!!";
              detailViewController.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphonerage.png"];

        } else if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"it.horizonmedia.testiap.prodottotest"]) {
            detailViewController.message = @"You made a Good Purchase!";
            detailViewController.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphonerage.png"];


        }
    } else {
        detailViewController.image = nil;
        detailViewController.message = @"Purchase to see comic!";
    }
}
```

}

Keep in mind, as I guess you did in the tutorial, that you have to replace your real product ids in the code.

Let me know if it works!